# AWS S3 csv export to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I have an s3 bucket to which a csv is uploaded/replaced regularly. However, i want the csv file to be sent and get imported by my wordpress plugin, import all. I’ve been thinking of using aws sns for this purpose but I cannot figure out how would I send the csv whenever it gets uploaded and to get imported by the WP plugin automatically.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Lambda functions [integrate well with S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) where you can have a Lambda function trigger whenever a given path in a S3 bucket is updated.  It looks like Wordpress has a [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/), and so you could write a short function in Python or the language of your choosing that makes a call to import the updated file.  ie -

```
csv -> S3 <- Lambda -> Wordpress
```

I am not familiar with Wordpress's API's, but I assume you can find whatever import call you're looking to make and include it in your Lambda function.